# Arraylist from insertion to database returning size 0

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im making a trivia game, and for some reason inserting question into the database is not working.
I made a class called q which has The question number (qnum), the String of the question itself (que), four possible answers (a1 - a4), and as an int the number of the correct answer (cor).

When I run the application, its supposed to run fillqt(), inserting 5 questions but later when I call getAllQuestions it tells me that the ArrayList's size is 0.

Please, can anyone help me find where the problem is?

```
public boolean insertQuestion(q q1, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    int rows = this.numberOfRows(db);
    q1.setQnum(rows);
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("question", q1.getQue());
    contentValues.put("A1", q1.getA1());
    contentValues.put("A2", q1.getA2());
    contentValues.put("A3", q1.getA3());
    contentValues.put("A4", q1.getA4());
    contentValues.put("cor", q1.getCor());
    db.insert("list", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

private void fillQT(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    q q1 = new q("What is the capital city of the Netherlands?", "Moscow", "Copenhagen", "Amsterdam", "Riga", 3);
    insertQuestion(q1, db);
    q q2 = new q("Who invented the scissors?", "Galileo Galilei", "George Washington", "Frederick Scissor", "Alexander Bell", 1);
    insertQuestion(q2, db);
    q q3 = new q("question value1", "A11", "A21", "A31", "A41", 0);
    insertQuestion(q3, db);
    q q4 = new q("question value2", "A12", "A22", "A32", "A42", 0);
    insertQuestion(q4, db);
    q q5 = new q("question value3", "A13", "A23", "A33", "A43", 0);
    insertQuestion(q5, db);
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("points", "0");
    cv.put("ft", true);
    db.insert(TRIVIA_TABLE_SECOND, "id = 0", cv);
}

public ArrayList<q> getAllQuestions() {
    ArrayList<q> array_list = new ArrayList<q>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from list", null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
        q temp = new q();
        temp.setQnum(res.getInt(0));
        temp.setQue(res.getString(1));
        temp.setA1(res.getString(2));
        temp.setA2(res.getString(3));
        temp.setA3(res.getString(4));
        temp.setA4(res.getString(5));
        temp.setCor(res.getInt(6));

        array_list.add(temp);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

Comment: Question: the database you are passing through fillQT is getWritableDatabase() ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not making that clearer

Comment: Sorry, I just created a simple Android project and I was able to insert and retrieve the list of questions. Created the table as: create table list( qnum integer primary key autoincrement, question text,A1 text,A2 text,A3 text, A4 text, cor integer); and called the insert as: dataBaseHelper.fillQT(dataBaseHelper.writableDatabase)